# Why is flush_rewrite_rules mandatory after registering custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I'm a newbie in the world of WP plugins.

I succesfully created custom post types and taxonomies and all is working well.

I have no idea of why we need to invoke `flush_rewrite_rules()` after registering custom taxonomies. It's a loose of time, for me, because it will recreate `.htaccess` from scratch.

But why? Why to recreate the `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: I didn't think I'd changed the meaning.  The main title still had "why".  I've reverted my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an expensive operation, so rather than it happening automatically you have to run it somewhere when you know your rewrites have changed.  There are also circumstances where WP may not know it needs to flush the rules: Deletion of a plugin that registers a CPT for example.

In your own plugin, run it on the activation and deactivation hooks.

If you use `flush_rewrite_rules( false )` then your `.htaccess` won't be resaved.